# Jmeter.log file not existing on Ubuntu

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I've created in Jmeter the follwing scenario thread: (see screenshot)

- -Machine : Ubuntu 18.04
- Jmeter Version : 5.2.1
- -Heap Size:HEAP=-Xms8192m -Xmx8192m

[image]

I run the test on the command line, but the problem I have , is the test doesn't stop, and I want to have a look on the logs,but in the file system of Jmeter I can not find the jmeter.log like on Windows (Apache\bin\jmeter.log).
I can't understand why Jmeter under Ubuntu no Jmeter.log has been generated, or it must be configured?

Answer (score 1):

*jmeter.log* file is generated by default at the folder you launch JMeter from. If you launch it from Desktop - it will be under `~/Desktop`, if you run it from `/tmp` - it will be under `/tmp`, etc.

So my expectation is that the *jmeter.log* file is being generated, you can locate it using [`find` command](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) like:

```
find / -type f -name jmeter.log
```

(better run it as [root](https://askubuntu.com/questions/617850/changing-from-user-to-superuser))

Also you can configure the logging subsystem via *log4j2.xml* file, it lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation. If you deleted the file by accident - there will no be any jmeter.log generated unless you put it back, you can get the copy from i.e. [JMeter Github page](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.2.1/bin/log4j2.xml). For configuration instructions see [How to Configure JMeter Logging](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging/) guide